# Alternative to workdays formula

Tags: sharepoint, excel-formula

Is there an alternative to workdays formula in Excel?

I am trying to convert

Business day: 6 to business date: 08/01/2018 (jan 8th)

I cannot use workday as SharePoint does not allow it. I found out any other should work as long as they don't use workday/networkdays.

Any formula is helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: Jan 8, 2017 - corrected

Comment: *facepalm* still stuck on 2017 sincere apologies. Its Jan 8, 2018

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:
The first day of the month is in Cell `A1` and Business Day is in cell `B1`

The following formula in cell C1 will give you the calculated business day without using the workday function.

```
=A1+TRUNC((B1-1)/5,0)*7+MOD((B1-1),5)+IF(WEEKDAY(A1)+MOD((B1-1),5)>=6,2,0)-IF(WEEKDAY(A1)=7,1,0)-IF(AND(OR(WEEKDAY(A1)=7,WEEKDAY(A1)=1),MOD((B1-1),5)=0),2,0)+1
```

Let me know if it works.

Edit: Formula Updated to resolve the error if the Day is Friday.

Comment: Hi, it works for some but when I entered start of month (01/01/2018) and day (20) it shows me Jan 28, 2018 which is a Sunday

Comment: Updated the formula. Now it will give the correct output.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your continuous help. One more issue. When I enter, Feb 1, 2018 and on cell B1 enter 2, it goes to Feb 5, 2018 instead of Feb 2, 2018 (which is a Friday)